# Exception encountered in the HTTPS Listener in WSO2 Integration Studio

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I followed [this tutorial](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/tutorials/integration-tutorials/sending-a-simple-message-to-a-datasource/).

But I get the below error when trying to run the artifacts using composite exporter.

```
FATAL {PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager} - Exception encountered in the HTTPS Listener. No more connections will be accepted by this transport org.apache.http.nio.reactor.IOReactorException: Failure binding socket to address 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:9164

Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
```

Please help me resolve this issue. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Happened Because Micro Integrator was running on the same port. Close the micro integrator and run it should work as expected